# How to bind enum to winform combobox using objectdatasource

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm binding a class to a windows form using the object data source: binding simple properties  to textboxes works fine, but i need to bind enum properties to comboboxes too, such as:

```
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Val1,
        Val2,
        Val3
    }
    private MyEnum enumVal;

    public MyEnum EnumVal
    {
        get { return enumVal; }
        set { enumVal = value; }
    }
```

How to accomplish this using a binding source? I've tried in various ways, but none of these works.
Thanks

Comment: I need the combobox stay syncronized with the EnumVal property of the class, i.e. if i change the EnumVal value, the combobox reflects the change, and viceversa, if i change the combobox value, the EnumVal property is updated too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it like this, but perhaps there exists a better way:

```
List<ListItem<MyEnum>> enumVals = new List<ListItem<MyEnum>>();

foreach( MyEnum m in Enum.GetValues (typeof(MyEnum) )
{
    enumVals.Add (new ListItem<MyEnum>(m, m.ToString());
}

myComboBox.DataSource = enumVals;
myComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Description";
```

Note that `ListItem<T>` is a custom class that I've created, which contains a Key property and a Description property.

In order to keep your property synchronized with the selected value of the combobox, you will have to :
- add a databinding to the combobox, so that the SelectedValue of the combobox is bound to your property
- make sure that the class which contains the property, implements INotifyPropertyChanged, so that when you change the property, the selected value of the combobox is changed as well.

```
myComboBox.DataBindings.Add ("SelectedValue", theBindingSource, "YourPropertyName");
```

and

```
public class TheClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private MyEnum _myField;

   public MyEnum MyPropertyName
   {
      get { return _myField; }
      set 
      {
         if( _myField != value )
         {
             _myField = value;
             if( PropertyChanged != null )
                  PropertyChanged ("MyPropertyName");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This would be good... but how to make this automatically syncronized with the property EnumVal? I'm using ObjectDataSource with automatic databinding.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

Define the enum eg:

```
public enum MyEnum{
  ItemOne,
  ItemTwo,
}
```

Within the form set the datasource of the combobox to the values of the enum eg:

```
myCombo.DataSource = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
```

To have the combo auto select a value based on a bound object, set the databinding of the combo eg:

```
class MyObject{
  private MyEnum myEnumProperty;
  public MyEnum MyEnumProperty{get {return myEnumProperty;}}
}
MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
myCombo.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedIndex", myObject, "MyEnumProperty");
```